# iOS - i want to change UITextView Height from single row to some fixed hight when i enter the text in swift3

Tags: ios, swift, constraints, uitextview

When the app loads I need to display 1 line in text view. when the user enters more words in the `textview`, I need to increase height automatically from 5 to 6 lines and then enable scrolling. can anyone help me?

[image]

Comment: You are using uitextview of textfield?

Comment: i am using UITextView.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can always increase the frame of the textView to a fixed height on editing start (textViewDidBeginEditing), if you really wish to have it fixed.

But that would mean if user fills it up again, it would stay that way.

You could also track editing changes (editingChanged) like this:

```
func textViewDidChange(_ textView: UITextView) {
    let width = textView.frame.size.width
    let height = CGFloat.greatestFiniteMagnitude
    let textViewSize = textView.sizeThatFits(CGSize(width: width, height: height)
    var textViewFrame = textView.frame
    textViewFrame.size = CGSize(width: width, height: textViewFrame.height)
    textView.frame = newFrame
}
```